# Python リストの要素を複数条件で削除したい

Tags: python, python3

下記のリストを複数条件で削除していますが、他に簡潔な方法はないでしょうか。
removeで値を指定して削除できるのは知っていますが、
リストの要素毎回変化するので、リストの番号を指定してスライスの方法で削除しております。

毎回削除する際にdel 〇〇を指定しないといけないので、簡潔に削除できる方法があれば
教えていただけますか。

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

リスト名
＊リストの要素毎回変化します。

```
list_a = ['ケーキ','りんご','アイス','みかん','どらやき','おはぎ']
```

全体のコード

```
# リスト
list_a = ['ケーキ','りんご','アイス','みかん','どらやき','おはぎ']

# 毎回スライスしたい値を指定
del list_a[0:1]
print(list_a)

del list_a[4]
print(list_a)

del list_a[2]
print(list_a)

['りんご', 'アイス', 'みかん', 'どらやき', 'おはぎ']
['りんご', 'アイス', 'みかん', 'どらやき']
['りんご', 'アイス', 'どらやき']
```

Comment: 削除するか残すかを判定する条件や手段があって変わらないのなら、それを関数として定義し、`map`関数・`for`ループ・リスト内包表記などで元のリストを判定して新しいリストを作れば良いと思われます。そういう判定条件や手段を追記してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。判定条件は一番最後の`del list_a[2]['りんご', 'アイス', 'どらやき']`になれば良いです。

Comment: 得たい判定条件の説明になっていませんね。要素が毎回変化するのに、なぜ、毎回スライスする値が指定できるのかが、説明されていないので理解できません。特定の抽出したい要素が決まっているのでしょうか？それをリストを見て人が目視判断してスライス値を決めているとか。

Comment: 「カタカナの要素だけ削除」や「〇〇アイスだけ削除」のような形ならわからなくもないですが、各要素に共通する項目が無い以上、"個別に要素を削除" の手間は変わらないと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。説明不足で申し訳ありません。スライスしたい値は決まっています。ただリストの中身が変化します。まずは順番としては`del list_a[0:1]`、`del list_a[4]`、`del list_a[2]`のように削除したいです。１行でまとめて削除できないでしょうか。

Comment: 「まずは」というからには何か書かれていない状況によって対象が変化する可能性があるように見えますが、そうしたものも含めてルールや手順として記述出来るようにしてみてください。

Comment: 「複数条件」と「複数の要素」では意味合いが変わってくるので、やりたいことと説明が噛み合っていない印象です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

削除したい要素が何かわかっている場合

```
list_a = ['ケーキ','りんご','アイス','みかん','どらやき','おはぎ']
del_item = 'ケーキ','みかん','おはぎ'
list_a = [s for s in list_a if s not in del_item]
print(list_a)  # ['りんご', 'アイス', 'どらやき']
```

削除したい要素の番号が何かわかっている場合

```
list_a = ['ケーキ','りんご','アイス','みかん','どらやき','おはぎ']
del_idx = 0, 3, 5
list_a = [s for i,s in enumerate(list_a) if i not in del_idx]
print(list_a)  # ['りんご', 'アイス', 'どらやき']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法で希望の結果になりました。

Answer (score 1):

リストの要素の順番が不定で構わないのであれば、単純なリスト (配列) の代わりに辞書を使った方が分かりやすくなりそうです。

```
dessert = {
  'ケーキ':1,
  'りんご':1,
  'アイス':1,
  'みかん':1,
  'どらやき':1,
  'おはぎ':1,
}

# 要素の削除
del dessert['ケーキ'], dessert['みかん'], dessert['おはぎ']

# キーの一覧を取得
print(dessert.keys())
```

参考:
[Pythonで辞書の要素を削除するclear, pop, popitem, del](https://note.nkmk.me/python-dict-clear-pop-popitem-del/)
[辞書に含まれるすべてのキーを取得する](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/dictionary/index8.html#section1)

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法も参考致します。